# Site not working after using CiviCRM its shows error in wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, civicrm-home

[image]Error :

Error: Could not create directory: /home/abcdraw/public_html/wp-content.

If you have moved an existing CiviCRM installation from one location or server to another there are several steps you will need to follow. They are detailed on this CiviCRM wiki page - http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location. A fix for the specific problem that caused this error message to be displayed is to set the value of the config_backend column in the civicrm_domain table to NULL. However we strongly recommend that you review and follow all the steps in that document.

Even Admin panel shows same error.
when i rename civicrm then site will blank.

Comment: is any one have answer?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange.  You are more likely to get a helpful answer if you could provide some more details.  What were you doing when you got this error message. What version of CiviCRM and WordPress are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error messages, this looks like an issue with WordPress rather than CiviCRM specifically.  There are several error messages for other WordPress plugins in addition to CiviCRM.

As a first step, I would suggest that you disable all of the plugins (including CiviCRM) and see if WordPress itself is working correctly.  If that works, you can then try enabling the plugins one by one to see which is causing the issue.

I notice that most of the errors refer to the path `/home/jumpcbu/...` but the CiviCRM error refers to `/home/abcdraw/...`.  This leads me to believe that you may have recently moved server.  In which case, this may be the cause of your problems.  I would suggest that you look at the documentation about [moving to a new server](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location) that is mentioned in the error message you posted.